# Add new FCurve to object (Python API)

Tags: python, scripting

How would one go about adding animation data (keyframes / *FCurves*) to an empty object using the Python API?

This is to be able to have full control over creation of keyframes and setting interpolation properties without having to use *Object.keyframe_insert*, finding the just made keyframe (as the function doesn't return the keyframe), and *then* adjusting interpolation properties.

---

## **Background:**

Many posts I've seen about adding animation data via the Python API uses the [*keyframe_insert*](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert) function of class *bpy_struct*, as seen here:

```
# Add keyframe to x axis on frame 1
obj.location.x = 1.23
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=0, frame=1)
```

[This Blender StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86825/76575) answer shows how one can access *FCurves* of an object once they are created.  Though, the post does not show how to create a *FCurve* from scratch.

To access the FCurve(s) that modifies a data_path on the currently selected object, one can do this (as shown in the post):

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
obj = context.object
action = obj.animation_data.action

# All location fcurves on the object
fcurves = [fc for fc in action.fcurves if fc.data_path == "location"]

# Iterate over each axis (of location property)
for fc in fcurves:
    # X axis would be axis == 0
    axis = fc.array_index
```

Before running the *keyframe_insert* function on an empty object, the [*animation_data*](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.animation_data) property of the *Object* is NoneType.  Running *keyframe_insert* sets this property to an instance of *AnimData* somehow. *animation_data.action* therefore is also non-existent, therefore one cannot begin adding FCurves (if even possible).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92287/editing-fcurve-keyframe-points-in-fast-mode   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111644/fast-keyframe-insertion  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64447/how-do-i-add-keyframes-to-a-newly-created-action-with-no-associated-objects

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32518/is-there-a-way-to-insert-keyframes-for-a-group-of-frames-using-python